# Does any implementation of `which` output "no" when executable cannot be found?

Tags: shell, history, which, bourne-shell

I am reading the [source code of the Maven wrapper written for the Bourne shell](https://github.com/apache/maven-wrapper/blob/102d7b50cd756b0ac922ef07378c1fe3c9686473/maven-wrapper-distribution/src/resources/mvnw#L103). I came across these lines:

```bash
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
    javaExecutable="$(which javac)"
    if [ -n "$javaExecutable" ] && ! [ "$(expr "$javaExecutable" : '\([^ ]*\)')" = "no" ]; then
# snip
```

`expr` when used with `arg1` and `arg2` and a `:` matches `arg1` against the regex `arg2`. Normally, the result would be the amount of matching characters, e.g.:

```
$ expr foobar : foo
3
```

However, when using capturing parentheses (`\(` and `\)`), it returns the content of the first capturing parentheses:

```
$ expr foobar : '\(foo\)'
foo
```

So far, so good.

If I evaluate the expression from the source quoted above on my machine, I get:

```
$ javaExecutable=$(which javac)
$ expr "$javaExecutable" : '\([^ ]*\)'
/usr/bin/javac
```

For a non-existing executable:

```
$ nonExistingExecutable=$(which sjdkfjkdsjfs)
$ expr "$nonExistingExecutable" : '\([^ ]*\)'
```

Which means that for a non-existing executable the output is a empty string with newline.

What's puzzling me in the source is how the output of `which javac` (`arg1` to `expr`) ever returns the string `no`?

Is there some version of `which` which, instead of returning nothing, returns `no` when no executable can be found?

If not, this statement always evaluates to true and that would be weird.

Comment: It's more likely that some version of `which` outputs "no 'foo' found" or something like that. The pattern `[^ ]*` matches a string of non-spaces, and usually a regex match picks the first hit, hitting the `no` at the start. I don't know what implementation would do that, though. zsh gives me "foo not found", and csh gives "foo: Command not found.".

Comment: @ilkkachu Good one, maybe Cygwin's `which` does this? Don't have a machine to try it on, currently.

Comment: "… and that would be weird." Well, to be fair, a lot of code *is* weird, and maven certainly is. One might debate whether `which` is the right tool here at all, but any reasonably competent programmer would have checked the return value of `which` instead of trying to parse a `no` substring from the output of a failed `which` invocation. You already know where this code is – please write a patch and submit it upstream :)

Comment: Maven is not written by people who understand shells. I wrote up a ticket about a command injection vulnerability in their quoting routines in 2013, and it mostly got ignored for almost a decade (later became CVE-2022-29599)

Comment: I second the point made by @CharlesDuffy. The code shown here is highly questionable, if you want to find an executable in a shell script, `which` is not the way to do it, `command -v` is (it’s available pretty much everywhere and it produces much more easily parseable output). And the rest of the script is even worse (I count at least a dozen issues not including the inconsistent coding style just in the bits leading up to the start of the first function definition).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Classically, `which` was a csh script, and it printed an error message like `no foo in /usr/bin:/bin` and returned a success status. (At least one common version, there may have been others that behaved differently.) Example [from FreeBSD 1.0](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/release/1.0.0_cvs/usr.bin/which/which.csh) (yes, that's ancient):

```
    if ( ! $?found ) then
    echo no $arg in $path
    endif
```

(This classic implementation is also notorious for loading the user's `.cshrc`, which could change the `PATH`, which would cause the output to be wrong.)

Modern systems usually have a different implementation of `which`, either written in C or in sh, and follow modern standards of dealing with error conditions: no output to stdout and a nonzero exit status.

Answer (score 5):

Technically that is checking if the *first word* (or rather, first sequence of non-space characters) in the output. And there are `which` implementations that don't remain silent:

- `zsh`'s `which foo` writes `foo not found` to stdout
- GNU `which foo` writes `which: no foo in (<contents of $PATH>)` to stderr
- And I don't have these around to test, but the manpages of a bunch of old Unixes have verbiage to the effect of "a diagnostic is printed ... if an executable file with the argument name was not found in the path" (though I would expect diagnostics to be printed to stderr).

I don't know which specific variant does print output starting with `no`, but GNU `which` might be inspired by it or be the inspiration for it.